# SignalR / XSockets to push XML messages

Tags: c#, push-notification, signalr, real-time

Is it possible to push XML messages to 3rd parties using SignalR or XSockets?

When I say 3rd parties I mean other website's clients.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure. Both SignalR and XSockets.NET can do that.
XSockets can actually push the messages to "anything" since there are templates for implementing custom protocols in XSockets and XSockets supports "cross-protcol communication".

By cross protocol I mean that you can connect anything having a network connection and let that "thing" publish/subscribe to events from XSockets.

Maybe a little bit of topic from what you asked but it opens up new possibilities when you can communicate between a browser and ANYTHING! :)

Regards
Uffe

Answer (score 0):

Both SignalR and XSockets use Javascript, so basically any client that support Javascript can use SignalR/XSockets. There are also client APIs for other clients like .NET and iOS.

Se the documentation:

https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki

http://xsockets.net/docs/supported-platforms